# how can i send data from my device to my php file via json

Tags: php, ios, json

i couldn't send data from my device to my php file. i am trying to send data from device using json. 
this is my php  code

```
$cevap = $_POST["cevap"];
echo $cevap;
```

and my client code:

```
NSString* postBody = @"cevap=ali";
NSLog(@"%@",postBody);
NSLog(@"postbody: %@",postBody);


NSData *postData = [postBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSURL* urlData = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yatanadam.com/sonuc.php"];



NSMutableURLRequest* request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlData 
                                                       cachePolicy:
                                NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];


[request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request1 setHTTPBody:postData];
 [request1 setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]] 
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self];
if (conn) {

    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

}
```

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

```
receivedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
result = [parser objectWithString:receivedString error:nil];
[parser release], parser = nil;
// Set tableData
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

i couldnt find the problem. can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you following two libraries, they will make it very easy to do your task:

- [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) - JSON library for objc
- [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) - HTTP library for objc